# how to make certain elements resize according to window with css

Tags: html, css

keep in mind: **I'm a beginner**

I looked everywhere and no answer really helped with this even tho it's a really simple concept I think

So basically I have a few < a > buttons inside a < div > (a div that takes up only 50% of its parent) and they look okay in full screen. But when I adjust the window size into a smaller one,the < a > elements get all messed up.

[here's a picture of the page in full screen](https://i.ibb.co/C1qcQ4h/Capture-d-cran-355.png)  and [here's one with a smaller window](https://i.ibb.co/hd9ghWj/Capture-d-cran-356.png)

I tried setting each button's width to 10% in the code below but it didn't change anything (I also tried using VH units and it didn't either)

here's the full HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device,initial-scale=1">
<title>home</title>
<style>
    #buttons_div>a{
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px 5px 2px 2px;
        width: 10%;
    }
    #buttons_div>a:hover{
        background-color: gray;
        border:10px solid;
        border-color: white;
    }
    #buttons_div{
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    div{
        padding-top: 30px;
        border: white 7px solid;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    div>img{
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black" align="center">
<div id="everything">   
<!------------------------------->
<div id="buttons_div">  
<a href="test.png">button1</a> 
<a href="test.png">button2</a> 
<a href="test.png">button3</a> 
<br>
</div>
<!------------------------------->
 <div id="imgdiv">
 <img src="stairs2.jpg">    
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/zabjo6f5/1/ let me know if this helps.

Comment: I agree that your screenshots look pretty goofy, and I can reproduce your issue with the provided code (although we do encourage you to post your code as a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), so that we don't have to copy-paste your code to JSFiddle or something).  However, I don't really know what your question is.  Are you just wondering the technical reason for WHY this is happening?  Are you asking for a fix?  Are you unsure if your general approach is good?

Comment: @Jake oh my question is the same as the title, I wanted to know to make them resize when the window resizes. As in I want them to look the same as the first picture only smaller

Comment: @ianworsley  I'm sorry if I'm missing something (I'm a beginner) but I'm not sure what's different about what u sent, doesn't it look the same?

Comment: So what do you want to happen when there physically isn't enough space for the three pieces of link text ("button1", "button2", "button3")?  It's not easy to dynamically adjust font size (based on your response, I suspect this is what you really want, but you will need SVGs or JavaScript for this), so typically people will either a) truncate/ellipsis the text if it doesn't fit, or b) wrap it onto multiple rows.  If you're worried about responsive design (eg, for supporting mobile devices), then either wrapping or a hamburger menu is probably what you will end up needing to do.

Comment: I suppose you could also consider one or media queries to shrink the size of your font depending on the screen width, but this could be a lot of work and without knowing the overall design goal, its hard to say if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: Using flex if you resize the page smaller the buttons will wrap down the page responsively but understanding now this is not what your after I understand I read your question wrong.

Comment: You have to use flex if you're after concise code that will look good on desktops and mobiles. Otherwise, you're in for many migraines and spaghetti code à la CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create rows and columns in you div element.If you don't the buttons are positioned on the same line, so if the line length Is too small the last element is positioned in a new line
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp

Comment: this works but I wanted them to stay in one line and just resize when the window gets smaller

Comment: Create a single row with 3 columns and set 33% width for each column. The elements inside the column will be automatically resize for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

a elements are inline and therefore doesn't listen to width or margin. Add `display: block` or `display:inline-block` if you want them aligned in one row

Answer (score 0):

Well, without understanding exactly what the OP's end goal is, I think they broadly have 3 options (pictured in the demo below):

1. SVG texts.  These will scale with the available space, but in my opinion are a lot more work than they're worth.  (As a sidenote, I don't know why the SVGs in the example below look so bad, but I'm confident they could be cleaned up if this is really the direction you want to go in).  I believe you'll also need a JS solution to make the `<text>` elements behave like links.
2. Just chop the text off.  Allow content to be clipped and/or ellipsied if there isn't enough space
3. Use media queries to make the text/buttons smaller at low screen widths in one or more increments.
4. (not pictured) put all these links into a sidebar, dropdown, or hamburger menu of some kind.  Eventually the screen will be small enough that shrinking the font/buttons will just make them unreadable, so a solution like this is probably the most robust (there's a reason that every mobile site ever has a hamburger menu)

```css
    .buttons_div>a {
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 12px;
      padding: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .buttons_div>a:hover {
      background-color: gray;
      border: 10px solid;
      border-color: white;
    }

    .buttons_div {
      width: 50%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      gap: 5px;
      
    }

    div {
      padding-top: 30px;
      border: white 7px solid;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    div>img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background-color: black;
    }

    svg{
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 12px;
      height: 40px;
      max-width: content;
    }
    
    text{
      stroke: black;
      font-size: 16px;
      transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(4px);
    }
    
    
 @media (max-width: 500px)
 {
   .mediaQuery{
      font-size: 8px;
      gap: 3px;
      
    }
    
    .mediaQuery>a{
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device,initial-scale=1">
    <title>home</title>

  </head>

  <body bgcolor="black" align="center">
    <div id="everything">
      <!------------------------------->
      <div class="buttons_div">
        <svg viewbox="0 0 100 30">
          <text y="50%" x="50%">button 1</text>
        </svg>
        <svg viewbox="0 0 100 30">
          <text y="50%" x="50%">button 2</text>
        </svg>
        <svg viewbox="0 0 100 30">
          <text y="50%" x="50%">button 3</text>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons_div">
        <a href="test.png">button1</a>
        <a href="test.png">button2</a>
        <a href="test.png">button3</a>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons_div mediaQuery">
        <a href="test.png">button1</a>
        <a href="test.png">button2</a>
        <a href="test.png">button3</a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!------------------------------->
    <div id="imgdiv">
      <img src="stairs2.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```